# Tulasi plant - leaves are turning black, getting dried & then dying

Tags: leaves

My Tulasi leaves are turning black partially and then getting dried & falling immediately. I don’t see any bug or anything and plant is becoming naked. Please help me to find the problem and it’s solution.
Attaching a photo of the plant condition.

[image]